# Linq Let Object not showing up in resuls - Creating a crosstab query

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, crosstab

I'm trying to convert a very simple linq tabular query into a crosstab.

```
dim q results
Zone Cube   QTY
100 LARGE   19
100 MEDIUM  4
100 SMALL   2
100 TINY    1
200 TINY    9
200 LARGE   1
200 TINY    2

linq to crosstab
Dim b = From f In (From x In q Group x By x.Zone Into Group) _
            Let MEDIUM As Object = (From r In f.Group Where _
                                    r.Cube = "MEDIUM" Select r.QTY).Sum _
             Let SMALL As Object = (From r In f.Group Where _
                                    r.Cube = "SMALL" Select r.QTY).Sum _
                                 Select New With {f.Zone ,SMALL,MEDIUM}
```

This should give me a crosstab table however I'm only getting the group column and the object columns are not showing up. 
I tried different things but I'm stuck. any ideas?

Comment: You've got two commas in a row in your query in the "New With" part... I'm not a VB person, but I'm surprised that even builds.

Comment: Thanks but it was just a typo. The code above should reflect the actual code.

Comment: Can you put this in the form of a short but complete program? That would really help us to help you.